# Where/When Can End-User View Android Application package name?

Tags: android

Question: Where/When would the end-user see the package name for my application? I've found these places thus far, thanks!

1. On the Android OS > Settings > App Manager > Running > Click mine
2. play.google.com URL get parameter ([example](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.talk))

Details: I'm prepared to publish an app using com.mydomain.myapp where myapp is currently a word in English but the user bases, phone carriers pre-installing the app, etc. will be in asia, latin america, africa, etc.

caveat1: Please take the details of this ex with a grain of salt as I've simplified it so you don't have to read a novel.

caveat2: I read [Androids docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) and the many stackoverflow posts re how to name your package w/out seeing reference to user exposure.

caveat3: My question would be "Does it matter what I name my package yadda yadda..." but I figure that would be subjective.

Answer (score 1):

I would not worry about the package name, just look Facebook app, which package's name is "com.facebook.katana" (may be mistaken, but the fact is that finishes on "katana".